# Execute code before DLLs are loaded by stub libraries

Tags: windows, dll, environment-variables

my application links against a 3rd party stub library that loads their DLL at application startup.
This DLL reads once at initialization a system environment variable which I would like to change in advance. Of course, I can change the environment variable before I start my application but I would like to change it from my application. Unfortunately, I cannot do this because the DLLs are already loaded in the entry point of my application. (main function)
Can I execute code to set the variable before this DLLs is loaded?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/delayload-delay-load-import?view=msvc-170

Comment: @HansPassant That is a nice idea but it would not work if the OP links with a .lib that has code in a global constructor etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [PE TLS callback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#tls-callback-functions) function.